# Is there another way to plot two separated graphs without ggplot?

Tags: r

I'm using `par(mfrow = c(1, 2))` to plot my graphs, but I was wondering if is another way to do it, I'm asking this cause I tried to find the mfrow function in R for data science book and I didn't find it...

Comment: If you type `??mfrow`  on the console, among the matches you'll find `graphics::par`, which makes sense considering that  `mfrow=` is an argument to `par` in your expression. If you read [`?par`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/par.html) and scroll down to `mfrow`, it suggests what it does, an `par(mfrow=c(1,2))` is using it correctly. If it isn't working in your case, then something about your code is not quite right given the circumstances (effective plot size, etc). Please share your full problem (code).

Comment: `mfrow` is the standard. You can also use `layout`. a lot of standard (older) r approaches may not appear in a new(ish) data science book (unfortunately)

Comment: See https://bookdown.org/ndphillips/YaRrr/arranging-plots-with-parmfrow-and-layout.html, https://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/layout.html, and http://rfunction.com/archives/1538

Comment: @r2evans The code is ok, I got the graphs, but I asked if there's another way to do it cause I didn't see this argument in R for data science (the book I'm using right now to study), I just found it searching how to plot more graphs. Another question, the two question marks in `??mfrow` works for every argument, and R gives me all the libraries and functions that mfrow is used as argument? Thanks!!!

Comment: `??` searches for topics/functions/arguments that are similar to the argument, so `??mfrow` searches for words *like* (using string-distance or such) "mfrow", and gives you zero or more help pages that _might_ be applicable. Look at the links I provided, they should be informative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are several methods to achieve it:

1. by plot_grid in cowplot

> cowplot::plot_grid(
> p1,
> p2,
> labels = c("A", "B")
> )

2. by patchwork

> library(patchwork)
> p1 + p2 + plot_annotation(
> tag_levels = "A",
> title = "The surprising truth about mtcars",
> subtitle = "These 3 plots will reveal yet-untold secrets about our beloved data-set",
> caption = "Disclaimer: None of these plots are insightful")

p1 and p2 are the two plots.